# SIGSEGV error when using queue<struct *>

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Hi I met a SIGSEGV error (Segmentation fault 11) when using struct * queue.
This code is about Huffman code, and I'm using priority_queue to implement algorithm. I guess the problem, and maybe my code needs initializing queue.
No matter how you try to solve it. Do I not use a pointer-type queue like this?
Please help me...

```
typedef struct NODE{
long long int freq;
string s;
struct NODE* left;
struct NODE* right;
}Node;

int main(){
priority_queue<Node*,vector<Node*>, compare > q;
Node* root;

scanf("%d",&n);
int power = find_power(n);

string a;
long long int b,total;

for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));

    cin >> a >> b;

    tmp->freq = b;
    tmp->s = a;
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;

    q.push(tmp);
}
scanf("%lld",&total);

result_fix = power * total;

for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {

    Node *z = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node*));

    Node* x = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    Node* y = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    x = q.top();
    q.pop();

    y = q.top();
    q.pop();

    z->left = x;
    z->right = y;
    z->s = "";
    z->freq = x->freq + y->freq;

    q.push(z);
    free(x);
    free(y);
}



root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
root = q.top();
q.pop();

if (!q.empty()) {
    printf("Queue is not empty!\n");
}

find_bit(root,0);

printf("%lld\n",result_fix);
printf("%lld\n",result_huff);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: If you are using C++ why are you coding as if you're using C? `(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node*));` (and incorrectly at that)

Comment: `string` is undeclared. `priority_queue` is undeclared. `vector` is undeclared.

Comment: Why are you typedef'ing structs? After `typedef struct NODE { ... } Node;` you have 3 types: `NODE`, `Node`, and `struct NODE`.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input. Always check its return value for failure.

Comment: @ CoryKramer  Then how do i allocate new NODE in this case?

Comment: You cannot use `malloc` to allocate space for anything containing non-trivial classes, like `std::string`. `malloc` doesn't run the string constructor, and any use of the non-constructed string will be undefined.

Comment: How about `Node *tmp = new Node();`?

Comment: @melpomene then how do i fix it????

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Assuming you include `<string>` and `<queue>`, there are still several undefined symbols: (`n`, `compare`, `find_power`, `result_fix`, `find_bit` and `result_huff`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

```
Node *z = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node*));
// ...
x = q.top();
```

Due to a double error, this is *undefined behaviour*:

- you allocated the memory necessary to store a `Node*` when you need memory for a `Node`;
- when you allocate memory with `malloc` the memory is left uninitialized: the object is not constructed. When you then affect it (`x = q.top();`), you call `Node::operator=` on a non-constructed object.

As a solution, I'd suggest to learn C++ and not write C with classes. But as a more specific solution:

```
Node z = q.top;
```

or

```
Node *const z = new Node(q.top);
```